# Reactjs How value is passed using onCompleted() in formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, formik

onCompleted() is called in useMutation because i want to open=true (open is a flag) when mutation is done than this flag value should pass to const App() so that open={open} and alert is shown. but the value of open is false throughout process. 
(2). If i set open={true}, than Welcome popUp shown on screen with login button, but when i press login button and onclick() triggers it gives error "cannot read property of 'setNewUser'", where setNewUser is const define in index file.

Register.js

```js
const App = ({ values, errors, touched, isSubmitting, dirty , isValid, setNewUser }) => {
 const styles= useStyles();

 const [open, setOpen]= useState(false) ;   //On new user dialog will open
// console.log(open)

  return (
  <div className={styles.root}>
  <Paper className={styles.paper}>
    <Form>

        <Field type="username" name="username"  placeholder="Username"  />

      <div>
        {touched.email && errors.email && <p>Invalid Email </p>}
        <Field type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
      </div>

      <div>
        {touched.password && errors.password && <p>Invalid password </p>}
        <Field type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"  />
      </div>

      <button  disabled={isSubmitting ||  !isValid || !dirty }>
        Register
      </button>

    </Form>
    </Paper>

    <Dialog
// Here is the flag, its not changing to true
    open={open}
    disableBackDropClick={true}>

        <DialogTitle>
                <VerifiedUserTwoTone className={styles.icon}/>   New Account created
        </DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
                <DialogContentText> Welcome {values.username} </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
                <button onClick={()=>setNewUser(false)}>Login</button>
        </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
};

const FormikApp = withFormik({
 //   enableReinitialize: true,

  mapPropsToValues({ email, password, username }) {
    return {
      username: username || " ",
      password: password || " ",
      email: email || " ",
    };
  },
  validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string()
      .email("Invalid email account")
      .required("field missing"),
    password: Yup.string()
      .min(8, "password is weak")
      .required()
  }),

  handleSubmit(values, {setStatus, props, setSubmitting }) {
  //event.preventDefault();
    props.createUser({
      variables: values,
    },   );

    setTimeout(()=>{
    setSubmitting(false)
    setStatus("sent");
    console.log("Thanks!");
  },1000);
  }
})(App);

const Register = () => {

  const [createUser,{loading,error}] = useMutation(REGISTER_MUTATION ,
  {
  onCompleted(){
//   setOpen(true)
  }}
  );
 if (loading) return <p>loading...</p>;
 if (error) return <p>An error occurred</p>;

 return <FormikApp  createUser={createUser} />;
};
export default Register;
```

index.js (local index for forms)

```js
import React,{useState} from "react";
import withRoot from "../withRoot";
import Login from "./Login"
import Register from "./Register"


export default withRoot(() => {
  const [newUser, setNewUser]= useState(true)
  return  newUser?            //if user is new than goto Register otherwise Login page
<Register setNewUser={setNewUser}/>
) : (
<Login/>
)
});
```

Login page is replica of Register (excluding mutation). I am stuck on this point, any contribution is welcomed. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't passed `setNewUser` down to the `<Register/>`:

```
return <FormikApp  createUser={createUser} setNewUser={props.setNewUser} />;
```

You cannot use `setOpen` in `onCompleted` as it's defined inside child. You need to define it higher (in `<Register />`) and pass value (`open`) and setter (`setOpen`) as props.